# (Presumable) false error in Android Studio, but compiler and app run fine

Tags: c++, android-studio, cmake, android-ndk

I have tried what most similar questions about false positives say: delete either the .idea/ folder (even ~/.gradle), exit project, reload, invalidate cache & restart, etc.  I've also ran refresh c++ linked libraries just in case.

Now just a background: my entire project is fine in regards to the IDE lint checker.  All files show proper warnings, etc.  Except for this one singular line in my c++ side.  (I'll show the whole method for context).  I can build and run my project just fine, and when I even invoke this logic portion of the app, it behaves as expected, with no problems.

```cpp
// Header (relevant member variable)
class MyClass {
private:
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> mArrayOfFooBars
}

// MyClass.cpp
void MyClass::updateModel(int index, const std::vector<int>& fooBars) {
    this->mArrayOfFooBars[index].assign(fooBars.begin(), fooBars.end());
    doMoreCalculations();
}
```

In Android Studio `foobars.begin()` and `fooBars.end()` are maked with the following errors:

> Parameter type mismatch: Types 'const int' and 'std::vector>::const_iterator' are not compatible
>
> Parameter type mismatch: Types 'unsigned int' and 'const int' and 'std::vector>::const_iterator' are not compatible

This brings me to believe that perhaps there is an error with the linter, or maybe I have some compiler settings wrong and this should in fact be a compiler error.  Either way, I'll try to provide as many settings as I feel are relavent, hopefully somebody can provide some useful suggestions.

- Gradle Plugin Ver: 3.6.3 (recent)
- Gradle Version: 5.6.4
- SDK ver: 29
- Build Tools Ver: 29.0.3
- NDK (Side by side) - Not installed (Not really sure what this is)
- CMake: 3.10.2 & 3.6.4111459 installed (probably only need one of these?)
- SDK Platform-Tools (update available for 30.0.0)
- SDK Tools: 26.1.1

I checked my linter settings (inspections) and didn't find any error level inspections for this:

[image]

And that's all I can think of, I'll just continue developing as normal, but it bothers me that it's there.  So any help in eliminating this rogue error will be appreciated!

Comment: the code looks fine to me and neither gcc nor clang with `-Wall -Wextra` show any warnings/errors.

Comment: Thanks for checking!  I'm assuming this has something to due with my Android Studio configuration then

Answer (score 0):

Errors in the IDE that doesn't show up as part of the build aren't unusual in Android Studio. The build and the IDE do not use the same toolchain. Old versions of Studio use CLion's C++ parser, which was often wrong because parsing C++ is notoriously difficult. New versions are starting to use clangd but it's not necessarily the same version of Clang as the build is using.

When you see issues like this odds are it'll be better in a newer version of AS, but it's often worth filing a bug to make sure it's on someone's radar.